# Fixing incorrect user role output

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I'm trying to target specific users with certain roles to display them on a page. When I output the data, all the users should be showing "author" but instead are showing "administrator" when they aren't admins.

Here's the code I've used:

```
<?php 
  $users = array_merge( get_users( 'role=author&order=ASC' ), get_users( 'role=contributors&order=ASC' ) );
  usort($users, create_function('$a, $b', 'return strnatcasecmp($a->last_name, $b->last_name);'));
  foreach($users as $user) : 

    $authorID = $user->ID;
    $authorRole = get_author_role($authorID);
?>

    <div class="card default">
      <div class="info">
        <p class="title"><?php echo $authorRole;?></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**EDIT: Added the Get_author_role function**

```
  function get_author_role() {
    global $authordata;

    $author_roles = $authordata->roles;
    $author_role = array_shift($author_roles);

    return $author_role;
  }
```

This method works for all other variables like, Name, email, picture, etc. I'm unsure why this is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the code of `get_author_role` method?

Comment: Sorry, I keep forgetting about that. I added it to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is from your get_author_role function. This function will return the first user role [In your case Administrator].

**Why**: Your function doesn't require any parameters.

**Solution**: Instead of using array_shift, use array_filter like :
I assume you have a User class with method getRole(). And your $authordata contains an array of User object.

```
     function get_author_role(int $userId) {
        global $authordata;

        $author_roles = $authordata;
        $author_role = array_filter($author_roles, function(User $user) use ($userId) {
            return $user->getRole();
        });

        return $author_role;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work. I get this message for the functions.php file:
Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in...on line 83. That line is the end of the $author_role definition.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the role contributors you have used. It is contributor.

```
<?php 
      $users = array_merge( get_users( 'role=author&order=ASC' ), get_users( 'role=contributor&order=ASC' ) );
      usort($users, create_function('$a, $b', 'return strnatcasecmp($a->last_name, $b->last_name);'));
      foreach($users as $user) : 

        $authorID = $user->ID;
        $authorRole = get_author_role($user);
    ?>

        <div class="card default">
          <div class="info">
            <p class="title"><?php echo $authorRole;?></p>
          </div>
        </div>
    <?php 
    function get_author_role($user) {
        global $authordata;

        $author_roles = $user->roles;
        $author_role = array_shift($author_roles);

        return $author_role;
      }
```

?>

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either. I get "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in...functions.php" on line 81. Whereas Line 81 is `$author_roles = $user->roles;`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help, while they didn't work for my particular application, the following did. Troubleshooting after those suggestions *did* lead me to finding this solution though.

Keeping the function the same:

```
  function get_author_role() {

    global $authordata;

    $author_roles = $authordata->roles;
    $author_role = array_shift($author_roles);

    return $author_role;
  }
```

But changing my `foreach` to:

```
$authorID = $user->ID;
$authorMeta = get_userdata( $authorID );
$authorRole = $authorMeta->roles;
```

This captured all potential roles in an array. I was able to then implode those results into a comma separated list, displaying each value.

```
<p class="title"><?php echo implode(", ", $authorRole);?></p>
```

Thanks again!